# combining surf and contour gnuplot for engine data

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

as I want to visualize an engine map using LaTeX, I'm having some problems where I am unable to find a fix. To be fair, I'm not the most experienced Tex user, so I hope one of you has got the answers for me. I'll start off with my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title= Title here $\lbrack - \rbrack$, xlabel=x $\lbrack - \rbrack$, ylabel=y $\lbrack - \rbrack$, 
width=0.9\textwidth, height=0.9\textwidth,
label style = {font=\small}, tick label style = {font=\scriptsize},
y label style={yshift=-2mm},x label style={yshift=2mm},grid=major,
view={0}{90}, 
colorbar,
colorbar style={ytick={200,210,...,300,370}},
ymin=0,ymax=20,
xmin=800, xmax=4000,
]


\addplot3 [surf,shader=interp, scatter,mark=o, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=0pt,yshift=0pt,anchor=north,font=\tiny},]coordinates{
(1000,1,370)    (1600,1,355)    (2000,1,360)    (2600,1,361)    

(1000,3,240)    (1600,3,245)    (2000,3,243)    (2600,3,246)    

(1000,6,224)    (1600,6,216)    (2000,6,212)    (2600,6,218)

(1000,9,230)    (1600,9,211)    (2000,9,330)    (2600,9,221)    

(1000,9,230)    (1600,12,221)   (2000,12,222)   (2600,12,231)

};


\addplot3 [contour gnuplot={number=8}, thick]coordinates
{
(1000,1,370)    (1600,1,355)    (2000,1,360)    (2600,1,361)    

(100,3,240) (1600,3,245)    (2000,3,243)    (2600,3,246)    

(1000,6,224)    (1600,6,216)    (2000,6,212)    (2600,6,218)

(1000,9,230)    (1600,9,211)    (2000,9,330)    (2600,9,221)    

(1000,9,230)    (1600,12,221)   (2000,12,222)   (2600,12,231)

};



        \pgfkeys{
        /pgf/number format/set thousands separator = }


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{none}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

After several attempts, I'm kind of happy it is at least running, but there are some things I'd like to improve:

- (How) can I modify the range of the contour plot? E.g. Id like to have it separated in 200,210,...,300,400 ?[answered]
- Is there any way to "smoothen" the outlines of the contour plot? The smooth-feature totally changes the whole plot.
- Is there any way to get the outlines of the contour plot in simple black?
- Is there a chance to have the range of the contour-plot without white background?

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Typically it is better to ask only a single question per question.

Comment: Hello @samcarter, the code posted above is pretty much a stripped-off example of what it really looks like. If I'd reduce it any further, I think the problems won't be visualized.

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228 A good minimal working example should also include the required packages etc.

Comment: Thank you for making things clear to me @samcarter, I just edited my example above to an MWE. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

> (How) can I modify the range of the contour plot? E.g. Id like to have it separated in 200,210,...,300,400 ?

The z-range of the plot can be adjusted using `point meta max=400`.

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title= Title here $\lbrack - \rbrack$, 
xlabel=x $\lbrack - \rbrack$,
ylabel=y $\lbrack - \rbrack$, 
width=0.9\textwidth, height=0.9\textwidth,
label style = {font=\small}, 
tick label style = {font=\scriptsize},
y label style={yshift=-2mm},
x label style={yshift=2mm},
grid=major,
view={0}{90}, 
colorbar,
colorbar style={ytick={200,210,...,300,400}},
ymin=0,ymax=20,
xmin=800, xmax=4000,
point meta max=400
]


\addplot3 [surf,shader=interp, scatter,mark=o, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=0pt,yshift=0pt,anchor=north,font=\tiny},]coordinates{
(1000,1,370)    (1600,1,355)    (2000,1,360)    (2600,1,361)    

(1000,3,240)    (1600,3,245)    (2000,3,243)    (2600,3,246)    

(1000,6,224)    (1600,6,216)    (2000,6,212)    (2600,6,218)

(1000,9,230)    (1600,9,211)    (2000,9,330)    (2600,9,221)    

(1000,9,230)    (1600,12,221)   (2000,12,222)   (2600,12,231)

};


\addplot3 [contour gnuplot={number=8}, thick]coordinates
{
(1000,1,370)    (1600,1,355)    (2000,1,360)    (2600,1,361)    

(100,3,240) (1600,3,245)    (2000,3,243)    (2600,3,246)    

(1000,6,224)    (1600,6,216)    (2000,6,212)    (2600,6,218)

(1000,9,230)    (1600,9,211)    (2000,9,330)    (2600,9,221)    

(1000,9,230)    (1600,12,221)   (2000,12,222)   (2600,12,231)

};



        \pgfkeys{
        /pgf/number format/set thousands separator = }


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{none}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @samcarter for your help! Are there any ideas to fix the other problems?

Comment: @ibofumo Unfortunately not.

Comment: too bad, but thank you for your help!